# jQuery - Getting the value of a select, by name, from a form object

Tags: jquery

I have a form:

```html
<form id="myForm">
    <select name="mySelect">                
        <option value="250">250</option>                    
        <option value="500">500</option>
    </select>
    <input id="submit-123" type="submit" />
</form>
```

And I need to get the value of the submit in a clever kind of way. There are multiple forms on the page, so I need to get the one related to the submit button that has been clicked.

```jquery
var form = $('#submit-123').closest('form');
```

But I can't work out how to get the value of the select, without referencing the index (it needs to be more robust than that).

The closest I've gotten is using: `form.children()` but I still can't work out how to accurately target the select.

I'm a JS newbie and any help would be greatly appreciated.

---

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work for you,

```
$('#submit-123').siblings('select[name="mySelect"]').val()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this to get related form of submit button clicked

```
   $('form').has('#submit-123').find('select');
```

or

```
   $(this).prev('select');
```

or

```
   $(this).closes('form').find('select');
```

to get value from that select

```
   $('form').has('#submit-123').find('select').val();
```

or

```
   $(this).prev('select').val();
```

**Complete code**

```
$(':submit').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // just for stop redirect, you may not need this
    alert($('form').has(this).find('select').val());
});
```

**[DEMO 1](http://jsfiddle.net/xv6cs/)**

**OR**

```
$(':submit').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // just for stop redirect, you may not need this
    alert($(this).prev('select').val());
});
```

**[DEMO 2](http://jsfiddle.net/qstjL/)**

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

```
<form id="myForm">
<select name="mySelect">                
    <option value="250">250</option>                    
    <option value="500">500</option>
</select>
<input id="submit-123" type="submit" />
</form>
```

**SCRIPT**

```
$("input:submit").click(function(){
    var value = $(this).closest('form').find('select').val();
    return false;
});
```